# list index error from regex

Tags: python, regex

I have following function that gives me errors.
It should extract the IP from the website url
Sometimes it works sometimes i get following error:

```
File "test.py", line 30, in getIPextA
address = grab[0]                    # get address as a string
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Function:

```
def getIPextA():
"""
Version A Get external ip from "http://checkip.dyndns.org/"
"""
site=geturldata("http://checkip.dyndns.org/")
if site =="" : return [0,0,0,0]
grab = re.findall('\d{2,3}.\d{2,3}.\d{2,3}.\d{2,3}',site)
address = grab[0]                    # get address as a string
return map(int,address.split('.'))   # as an integer list
```

Comment: am I allowed to quote that url or do i need to mask it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. What is `geturldata`?

Comment: geturldata() gets all the data from the url page as a long string with some error checking if the url fails etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error when the IP address could not match the regex. The reason is probably that you sometimes have an IP containing a one-digit part. These are also valid IPs. You should also escape the dot, because a dot in a regex means that it can match any char.

```
grab = re.findall('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}',site)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this instead

```
    match = re.search(r' (\d{1,3}) \. (\d{1,3}) \. (\d{1,3}) \. (\d{1,3}) ', site, flags=re.X)
    return match.groups() if match else [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

which allows between one and three digits in each octet, and has the dots `.` escaped properly as well. The `flags` parameter allows me to add insignificant whitespace so that the regex is more readable. Each octet is cointained in parentheses, so the `MatchObject` will return a list of four decimal strings if you call its `groups` method.

But I don't know what your `geturldata` function is so I can't help any more.